# Complex Filter in one Opration

Tags: javascript, performance, object-oriented, array

I am working on a Data-based application.

I wrote a code to filter the table.
The table has `String` and `Numbers`.

I some filter for string, like min word count, max word count, string includes and excludes
For Numbers, I also have filters like min, max.

This is my code,

```
var props = {
  rows: [
    {
      keywordIdeaMetrics: {
        competition: "LOW",
        monthlySearchVolumes: [
          {
            month: "JUNE",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "60500",
          },
          {
            month: "JULY",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "49500",
          },
          {
            month: "AUGUST",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "SEPTEMBER",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "33100",
          },
          {
            month: "OCTOBER",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "33100",
          },
          {
            month: "NOVEMBER",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "DECEMBER",
            year: "2020",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "JANUARY",
            year: "2021",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "FEBRUARY",
            year: "2021",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "MARCH",
            year: "2021",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "APRIL",
            year: "2021",
            monthlySearches: "40500",
          },
          {
            month: "MAY",
            year: "2021",
            monthlySearches: "49500",
          },
        ],
        avgMonthlySearches: "40500",
        competitionIndex: "2",
        lowTopOfPageBidMicros: "1537028",
        highTopOfPageBidMicros: "31453279",
      },
      text: "paleo diet",
      keywordAnnotations: {},
    },
    // almost 500 more objects
  ],
};

var filters = [
  {
    property: "avgMonthlySearches",
    type: "NUMBER",
    min: 100,
  },
  {
    property: "keyword",
    filterType: "INCLUDE",
    type: "STRING",
    wordFilterType: "Any word",
    words: ["how", "what"],
  },
];

var result = props.rows.filter((row) => {
  var isPassed = false;
  var FiltersLen = filters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FiltersLen; i++) {
    var filter = filters[i];
    if (filter.property === "keyword") {
      row.keywordIdeaMetrics.keyword = row.text;
    }
    if (filter.type === "NUMBER") {
      if (filter.min && filter.max) {
        if (
          Number(row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]) > filter.min &&
          Number(row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]) < filter.max
        ) {
          isPassed = true;
        }
      }
      if (
        filter.min &&
        Number(row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]) > filter.min
      ) {
        isPassed = true;
      }
      if (
        filter.max &&
        Number(row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]) < filter.max
      ) {
        isPassed = true;
      }
    } else if (filter.type === "STRING") {
      if (filter.filterType === "INCLUDE") {
        if (filter.wordFilterType === "Any word") {
          if (
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
            filter.words.some(function (v) {
              return (
                row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf(v) >= 0
              );
            })
          ) {
            isPassed = true;
          }
        } else if (filter.wordFilterType === "All words") {
          if (
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
            filter.words.every((item) =>
              row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(item)
            )
          ) {
            isPassed = true;
          }
        }
      } else if (filter.filterType === "EXCLUDE") {
        if (filter.wordFilterType === "Any word") {
          if (
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
            filter.words.some(function (v) {
              return (
                !row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf(v) >= 0
              );
            })
          ) {
            isPassed = true;
          }
        } else if (filter.wordFilterType === "All words") {
          if (
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
            filter.words.every(
              (item) =>
                !row.keywordIdeaMetrics[filter.property]
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(item)
            )
          ) {
            isPassed = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (isPassed) {
      if (i === FiltersLen - 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        isPassed = false;
      }
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

I want to know is there any better way to perform this filter (performance-wise)?

**Note:** *It's a real-world project.*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I update the question can you please further look at it?

Comment: Looks good, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Its seems like you have all the logic to filter the `rows` centralised, and the use the external `filters` array to decide which filters to apply. This makes your code kind of complex.

Why not let each of the entries in `filters` be a function that takes a `row` as an input, and returns `true` if it should be filtered? Then, you could simply change the way you filter `rows` to something like:

```js
rows.filter(row => filters.some(filter => filter(row)))
```

Also, that makes it easier to modify the filters, as each one of them is separated into its own function.

Comment: seems nice can you please share the code to create the filter function? Because I am using react with the functional component. How to create and update functions (on user input?)

Answer (score 2):

You have provided limited information in regard to what and how to filter the data. Thus this review looks at just an array (table of records) and how to build complex searches using functions built into the filter object.

### Complex filters

As you have the filter you filter while you parse the filter. This adds overhead to processing the table.

It also makes the filter function many times more complex than it should be. Adding additional filters will increase that complexity, and as all filters rely on the same parser if you change just part of one you risk breaking all filters.; This makes the code hard to maintain and very susceptible to bugs.

Defining filters as named functions lets you separate the logic for each filter from any other filters. Defining a new type of filter is then just a matter of adding the filter function.

The defined function must use a consistent interface, and have access to a state that provides the information needed to perform the filter operation.

The example filter functions below takes the `rec` (record AKA row) as an argument and returns a `Boolean`
The filter properties (eg `min`, `max`) are bound to the function via the `this` token

**Note** If the filter function is in an array you will need to bind the function to each items using [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

### Filter types

The following code defines 6 filters by named functions.

- `filters.all`  Returns true if all filters in an array filters match
- `filters.number.minMax`  Returns true if  min <= field <= max
- `filter.string.include.all` Returns true if all words are included
- `filter.string.include.any` Returns true if any word is included
- `filter.string.exclude.all` You get the picture
- `filter.string.exclude.any` ditto

```
const filters = {
    all(rec) {
        return this.filters.every(filter => filter.filter.bind(filter)(rec));
    },
    number: {
        minMax(rec) {
            const val = Number(rec[this.field]);
            return (this.min ?? -Infinity) <= val && (this.max ?? Infinity) >= val;
        },
    },
    string: {
        include: {
            all(rec) {
                const val = rec[this.field].toLowerCase();
                return this.words.every(str => val.includes(str.toLowerCase()));
            },
            any(rec) {
                const val = rec[this.field].toLowerCase();
                return this.words.some(str => val.includes(str.toLowerCase()));
            }
        },
        exclude: {
            all(rec) {
                const val = rec[this.field].toLowerCase();
                return this.words.every(str => !val.includes(str.toLowerCase()));
            },
            any(rec) {
                const val = rec[this.field].toLowerCase();
                return this.words.some(str => !val.includes(str.toLowerCase()));
            }
        }
    },
};
```

You then define a filter using

```
const testFilter = {
    filter: filters.all,
    filters: [{
            filter: filters.number.minMax,
            field: "monthlySearches",
            min: 40500,
        }, {
            filter: filters.string.include.any,
            field: "month",
            words: ["A", "B"],
        },
    ],
};
```

And to use the filter you apply the via a function that takes the filter and an array of records

```
function applyFilter(filter, table) {
    return table.filter(filter.filter.bind(filter));
}
const result = applyFilter(testFilter, rows);
```

### Encapsulate filter state

To encapsulate each filter and ensure that it has the correct state to perform its task you can define the filter function using a function. Example below the function  `filters.number.minMax` returns the filter function with the filter state (`field`, `min`, `max`) encapsulate via closure.

You can also provide a filter create function. eg

```
// define
const filters = {   
    number: {
        minMax(field, min, max) {
            return (rec) => {
                const val = Number(rec[field]);
                return (min ?? -Infinity) <= val && (max ?? Infinity) >= val;
            }
        },
    },
};

// create
const testFilter = {
   filter: filters.number.minMax("monthlySearches", 40000),
}
```

Comment: I will definitely follow this! BTW in meanwhile, I just have a question I have 500-1000 rows to filter! Is this work fine? (performance-wise?)

Comment: @RohitNishad 1000 rows Yes easy fast, depending on the filter of course. Should do a few hundred thousand + rows per second on a low end device

Comment: Well, You are calling `.filter` function too many time which. Which causes lag in UI.

Comment: @RohitNishad The example only calls a filter function at most once per filter per record. The order of filters called will make a difference in number of calls. If you experience UI lag you should should move the task to a separate thread or break the task into smaller chunks

Comment: seams complicated :( any blog or link?